# does configuration properties on hdfs-site.xml applies to NameNode in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I recently set up a test environment cluster for `hadoop` -One master and two slaves.

Master is NOT a dataNode (although some use master node as both master and slave).
So basically I have 2 datanodes. The default configuration for replication is 3.
Initially, I did not change any configuration on `conf/hdfs-site.xml`. I was getting error `could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of 1`.
I then changed the configuration in `conf/hdfs-site.xml` in both my master and slave as follows:

```
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>3</value>
</property>
```

and lo! everything worked fine. 
My question is: does this configuration applies to NameNode or DatNode although I changed hdfs-site.xml in all my datanodes and NameNodes.

if my understanding is correct, NameNode allocates the block for datanodes. so replication  configuration in `master` or `NameNode` is important and probably not needed in `datanodes`. Is this correct?

I am confused with the actual purpose of different xml in hadoop framework: from my little understanding:

1) `core-site.xml` - configuration parameters for the entire framework, such as where the logs files should go, what is the default name of the filesystem etc

2) `hdfs-site.xml` - applies to individual datanodes. how many replication, data dir in the local filesystem of the datanode, size of the block etc

3) `mapred-site.xml` - applies to datanode and gives configuration for the task tracker.

please correct if this is wrong. These configuration files are not well explained in the tutorials I had. so it comes from my look into these files in the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

This is my understanding and I may be wrong.

{hdfs-site.xml} - is to for the properties of HDFS(Hadoop Distributed File System)
{mapred-site.xml} - is to for the properties of MapReduce
{core-site.xml} - is for other properties which touch both HDFS and MapReduce

Comment: This does not answer the question though.

Comment: Hello Robby, I think even I only answered half of the question(why different xmls). I am not sure why the error was coming when there were no changes. I will try to play around in my setup to see what was causing it.

Answer (score 0):

this is usually caused by insufficient space.

please check the total capacity of your cluster and used, remaining ratio using

```
  hdfs dfsadmin -report
```

also check dfs.datanode.du.reserved in the hdfs-site.xml, if this value is larger than your remained capacity

look for other possible causes explained [here](http://cloudcelebrity.wordpress.com/2013/11/25/handling-hadoop-error-could-only-be-replicated-to-0-nodes-instead-of-1-during-copying-data-to-hdfs-or-with-mapreduce-jobs/)

Comment: can you explain what you tried before downvoting it ?

Comment: I think who downvoted the answer wanted to say "this is more like a comment than it is an answer"

Comment: it has to be a comment only as there are many reasons by which you can endup getting this error the very basic one is your dfs is full or your block size is not correctly set, there are many few others which is specified in the link i provided..  at the end one has to work himself to fix issues which sm1 is facing other's can only give pointers..

Comment: it's not I who downvoted it but for me the answer is somehow incomplete

Comment: i was not saying to you anyways this was actually generic. cheers.. :)

Comment: I did not downvote it, but it did not answer my question