# why does my hadoop command does not work?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have my `hadoop cluster` set up with one `master` and two `slaves.`
when I type

```
hadoop fs -ls 
ls: Cannot access .: No such file or directory.
```

But when I type the following:

```
hadoop fs -ls /
Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x   - Mike supergroup          0 2014-06-24 00:24 /usr
```

I get the same output both on master and slaves. why `hadoop fs -ls` does not work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  hadoop fs -ls
```

This tries to list current user's home directory on hdfs.  since i think **/user/{username}** directory doesn't exist in your case hence you get the error,

```
  hadoop fs -ls /
```

you are specifically telling it to list root directory which it does successfully as it exist.

Comment: I have another question posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422642/why-the-number-of-blocks-used-are-different-in-hadoop

Comment: and one more question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24416817/does-configuration-properties-on-hdfs-site-xml-applies-to-namenode-in-hadoop